# Is "being raised" Simple Past or Present Perfect?

Tags: gerunds

While this is a legend, there are many modern stories about children being raised by wolves.

If I analyze this carefully from my understanding the context meaning of "being raised" in the sentence would actually be "A repeated action in an unspecified period between the past and now." which is a rule in present perfect, but when I checked the rule there's no example of 'being' included in the form.

If I take 'being' as a linking verb then raised would only be a simple past.

Comment: Neither: *being raised* is a gerundial passive. The passive independent clause *Children are raised by wolves* is cast as a gerund clause--*gerund* being the traditional name for an *-ing* form which may act as a noun--so that it may be employed as the object of the preposition *about*.

Comment: To expand on StoneyB's comment: it is simple (not perfect) present in the same sense that "wolves raising children" is simple present; "be(ing)" is added because the structure/order is reversed, making "children" the subject of a passive phrase (as in "many people view the paintings" ↔ "the paintings are viewed by many people".)